# How can I use jinja2 in flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am making a website using flask,this the directory:

[image]

I want to define a jinja2 template page named 'base.html' int the template directory，and it can be referenced anywhere:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="zh-CN">
{% block header %}
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Mind Fly</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon"  href="../static/images/head.ico"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}

    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="container">
            .....
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

here is the home page:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}  
    {% block body %}
    <div>
        <ul id="content">
            <li><img src="../static/images/book.jpg" ></li>
            <li><img src="../static/images/think.jpg" ></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

here is the register.py:

```
from flask import render_template, Flask
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

when I executed this, it raised "interval error 500", if I don't quote the base.html, I can get the home page correctly. I don't know whether the definition or the reference of the jinja2 template is wrong.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I see wrong with your code is that you need to initialize your `app` variable.

Add `app = Flask(__name__)` right below your import in register.py and you should be good to go!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Check this code [flaskbasic](http://code.runnable.com/VueKjh0U0fAEKmyE/basic_flask_exp-for-python)
I have run your code on runnable. There are some issues in your app directory, like you need to rename init.py to __init__py. Also import your app in your register.py

from app import app
Your templates are fine

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason, it was because i defined two templates of the same name in one page. Even though I commented out one of them, it still raised error, like this:

```
{% block body %}
{% endblock %}
<!--{% block body %}
{% endblock %}-->
```

Only if I delete the one commented one, the program can be executed correctly. I don't know why, the commented one still work.